# What does ordering mean in list/tree set in java

Tags: java

Java docs says that a "TreeSet keeps its elements ordered internally".

Here what does ordering mean?  Does it mean sorted? If so, then what is the difference between sorting and ordering?

Comment: @Thilo Ordered is more general than sorted.

Comment: In this case, it means sorted, though. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ordered" means that there is a defined order in which the elements can be retrieved. This means that when you iterate over the Collection, you know in which order you will get the elements.

In this case it does mean "sorted" (because the TreeSet arranges elements according to a given Comparator, i.e. it sorts them).

In other cases (such as a Queue), it can mean "insertion order".

In the case of a List, you can specify the order yourself (by assigning each element an index), and the List will keep them in this order (which is independent of insertion order or any sort order).

Contrast this to a HashSet, which makes no guarantees about the order of elements when retrieved.

Comment: A `List` would be the obvious example of an ordered but not [necessarily] sorted collection. `LinkedHashSet` has an order about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It is sorted using the natural sort order of the type of its elements (e.g. alphabetical  order for strings, numerical order for ints, etc), unless a comparator is provided to define sort order.

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

*From the [TreeSet Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).*

Comment: Then why doesnt the java doc say "the elements are sorted"

Comment: @Rekha - because ordering doesn't necessarily mean 'sorted' (like with alphabets). They could be reverse-ordered, or in what you consider a 'sorted' order, but you could also change the comparison function to do something else entirely.

Comment: "Sorted" probably would imply that the elements have been put into the correct order from a previous state where they weren't in that order. That is not the case with for example TreeSet - whenever an element is added to that set, it's added in the correct position, so sorting never becomes necessary.

Comment: @birryree +1 /
@Rekha to add to what birryree has said, the order comes from a `compareTo` method of a `Comparable` class, or the `compare` method of a `Comparator`.  In these methods, all that is *technically* required is that you return an integer.  I don't know why you would, but you could technically return an random integer if you felt like it.  The "order" comes from the `Comparator`, but it is not necessarily "sorted" in the sense that you might consider.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering in `TreeSet`, from the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> A NavigableSet implementation based on a `TreeMap`. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Here "natural ordering" means the class can implement [Interface Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), which allows you to specify the behavior of `compareTo()`.

You can also use the `TreeSet` constructor that allows you specify a `Comparator` class that will dictate the type of ordering: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Comparator)